# Auto-Trust internal-only services in IdentityServer environment

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

We have to develop a larger application with an Angular App on top and a lot of ASP.NET Core based Microservices under the hood.

Also we have to support external applications.
The external applications can be services without UI and also user GUI client applications.

Now the requirement is, that all internal Microservices are auto-trusted automatically and only for external Application the user should get the trust workflow in IdentityServer.

We're not sure how the workflow here should be configured or is be named in this scenario.
I think we need two different workflow configurations for internal and external application trusts.

Can anybody push me into the right direction which workflow and configuration fits most to our requirement?

Following providers we have to support:
- Simple Forms Authentication for our platform
- External Azure Active Directory

Comment: Either everything requires authorization or nothing. Just create regular accounts for your internal services and use client credentials flow (since the application is a confidential client, you can use the client secret safely). For external applications create external logins and use implicit/hybrid flows where you can't use code based authorization (client secret can't be stored securely in an application that you hand over to the customer)

Comment: So to verify that: we use the Client Credential Flow for internal applications and the hybrid workflow for external applications.
We register all application inside IdentityServer. But what about the user screen for authorize external services? We only want that the user gets the "do you want to share following profile data with that service?" screen for external applications, not for internal applications. What is the common way here.

Comment: Client credential flow is not an interactive flow (no UI), you authorize directly via code (i.e. `TokenClient` from IdentityServer4). It's meant for server-to-server communication and to tokens are issued to the application rather than **the user**, which sounds exactly what you are looking for. If you want impersonate/delegate a user to access his resources (by calling Facebook, Google API with it), let the user log in into your public app/gateway, cache the token and pass the jwt token around to your services or use it for the `HttpClient` calls to external api.

Comment: Thank you @Tseng I will focus on your recommendations now.